# how to upgrade Mysql 5.5.30 to 5.6.21 in Amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2

The current installation of mysql is 5.5.30 and it is in Amazon ec2
I want to upgrade it to 5.6.21

I used

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.6.21
```

But it says:

```
Version '5.6.21' for 'mysql-server' was not found
```

Any idea?

Comment: Every repository does not necessarily have the latest version of each program.  You might need to find one that has the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect version 5.6.21 just isn't offered in your distro's package manager.

You should be able to check which version(s) are reported as available if you run `apt-cache policy mysql-server`.

i.e.: here's the current output I get from Debian Wheezy:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1
  Version table:
     5.5.41-0+wheezy1 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
```

So 5.5.41 is the current version offered through the package manager.

You can [downloaded newer versions from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/getting-mysql.html) directly, and [install it manually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/linux-installation-debian.html).

Comment: This is a Amazon EC2 instance of the server.  Can the OP download and install manually this?

Comment: Wheezy is the stable repository.  You won't find the latest version of anything there.  Ubuntu is based on Debian Testing, and it's not even there.